# Usar cerrojos en metodo run

Tags: java, hilos

¿Es absurdo comenzar un metodo run con un cerrojo que se cierra y finalizarlo con un cerrojo que se abre?

```
Lock lock=new ReentrantLock();
public void run{
    lock.lock();
    //codigo del hilo
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Estoy teniendo problemas con un ejercicio de hilos y haciendo esto se soluciona pero no se si es algo absurdo y seria igual que programar sin concurrencia

Comment: Si publicas la parte relevante de tu codigo, podriamos darte una respuesta mas exhaustiva.

Comment: https://www.ctr.unican.es/asignaturas/procodis_3_ii/doc/procodis_3_03.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Como concepto no lo veo nada raro y mucho menos absurdo. Tu sabrás lo que haces ¿no?
Lo que no me gusta en tu código es que no utilizas try - finally. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
    lock.lock();    
    try {
         // ...
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

O incluso algo más defensivo todavía:

```
boolean locked = lock.tryLock();
if (locked) {
    try {...
```

Pero respondiendo otra vez a tu pregunta - no lo veo absurdo.